# Keyboard works on win 7 but not win 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Already made post about this, so let me explain again C works only if D is pressed S works only of Q is pressed and K works only if J is pressed, I trought it was hardware issuse so i cleaned my keyboard but those keys are still not working, after that i randomly tried that keybord on my win 7 machine and it was working perfectly fine, but its still not working on win 10 machine, any suggestions? I already tried to change usb port amd reinstall driver.

Comment: Did you try to install a Windows 7 driver on Windows 10? And what is the keyboard?

Comment: I have not, and its scorpion k9

Comment: The `geniusnet.com` website does not list any drivers for the [Scorpion K9](http://us.geniusnet.com/supports/scorpion-k9). I suggest in Device Manager to delete the devices whose drivers you installed, with their drivers, then reboot (you might need to use the mouse).

Comment: sorry for late answer but i noticed with keyboard input test that when i press some of keys that dont work it appears that i pressed f7 key

Comment: It might just be a hardware problem, not software. Try another keyboard.

Comment: its not, keyboard works nice on my other device